# How to get user input for switch statement in php?

Tags: php, user-input

As questioned above I'm trying to get user input in my PHP script to do further tasks. Is there any method in PHP to get user input like 'scanf()' used in C

```
<?php
echo "Swapping Numbers </br> Please select the method: </br>";
echo "1. Using 3rd variable </br> 2. Using add/sub </br> 3. Using mul/div";
//read user input $choice
switch($choice)
{
case 1:
        break;
case 2:
    break;
case 3:
    break;
default:
        echo "</br>You entered wrong choice";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the `STDIN` constant is pre-defined and available for you to use immediately.

You can get user input using [`fgets`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) and [`fscanf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fscanf.php)

```
<?php
$line = trim(fgets(STDIN));     // reads one line from STDIN
fscanf(STDIN, "%d\n", $number); // reads number from STDIN
```

For example

```
<?php
echo "Enter a number: ";
fscanf(STDIN, "%d\n", $number);
switch ($number) {
  case 1: echo "one\n"; break;
  case 2: echo "two\n"; break;
  case 3: echo "three\n"; break;
  default: echo "I can't count that high\n";
}
```

Check out the [I/O docs](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php) for more detailed information

Comment: @naomik- I added your code fscanf(STDIN, "%d\n", $choice);
switch($choice) but showing Warning: fscanf() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given then how to deal with this

Answer (score 1):

You should use [readline()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.readline.php) :

```
var_dump(readline('Enter number: '));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle user input from form element or from url.
 in your case you can use like this.

```
$choice = $_GET['choise'];
```

User will type like this

```
http://localhost/your_file_name.php?choise=option
```

than you should use your switch

```
switch($choice)
{
case 1:
        break;
case 2:
    break;
case 3:
    break;
default:
        echo "</br>You entered wrong choice";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I know using <form> is possible and i worked with this. Now I'm trying like scanf() in C'